# AWS Instance Scheduler will stop VMs ok, but will not start VMs

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-instance-scheduler

Why does AWS Instance Scheduler stop VMs ok,but will not start VMs.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Instance Scheduler is running if it stops the VMs.
It appers Instance Scheduler does not have the permissions to Start the VMs.
If your Volumes are encrypted, the aws-instance-scheduler-SchedulerRole-* role requires kms:CreateGrant on the Volume encyption keys.

Fix:
Locate the encryption key arn(s). Using the **EC2|Volumes** Console is an easy way to identify them all.

In IAM Console, edit **aws-instance-scheduler-SchedulerRole-***
Select **Add Permissions, Create Inline Policy**.
Select **JSON** tab

Add the following json:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "kms:CreateGrant"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxx:key/aaaaaaaaaaaaa",
                "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:xxxxx:key/bbbbbbbbbbbbb"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow"
        }
    ]
}
```

Select **Review policy**

Enter the name "**SchedulerPolicyKMSKeys**"

Select **Create policy**